# Having spectral density without plot

Tags: r

I want to have spectral density of a set of values

```
x.spec<-spectrum(datalist[1:128,1],log=c("no"))
```

this code plot form me a plot. but I dont want to have any plot. Is there any way, that I can ignore this plot and having only spectral density

```
x.spec$spec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x.spec<-spectrum(datalist[1:128,1],log=c("dB"),plot=FALSE)
```